# How to put together TypeScript, Vite, React and npm link?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, npm-link

I wrote a simple embryonic TypeScript package (published on a private registry) and I want to import it in a TypeScript React app created with Vite.

Everything works fine until I try *npm link* the two packages. Once linked, I'm still able to *build* the app through `npm run build` (actually the result is not tested yet), but local development environment launched through `npm run dev` continues to fail with following error.

**[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve entry for package "my-package". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json: Failed to resolve entry for package "my-package". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.**

Any idea?

Files in **my-package**.

**index.ts**

```js
export class User {
  public email?: string;
  public name?: string;

  constructor(src: Partial<User> = {}) {
    this.email = src.email || "-";
    this.name = src.name || "";
  }

  public isValid(): boolean {
    return this.email !== "-";
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "description": "my-package",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "16.11.11",
    "ts-node": "10.4.0",
    "typescript": "4.5.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepack": "tsc"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "ESNext"
  },
  "include": ["*.ts"]
}
```

Files in the **React app**.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true
  },
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

**vite.config.ts**

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
  build:        { outDir: "dist" },
  optimizeDeps: { exclude: ["my-package"] },
  plugins:      [react()],
  resolve:      { dedupe: ["my-package"] },
  server:       { hmr: { overlay: false } }
});
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into a similar issue.

Comment: Hi @EliWeb-Dev , A long time have passed and I've changed many things... Probably the most impacting change I applied is changing `tsconfig.json` with `"module": "commonjs"` in `my-package` and adding [@rollup/plugin-commonjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-commonjs) to my React app